A calculated dimension that combines years (if the year is completed) and months (if the year is not completed)
I'm trying to create a calculated dimension in the diagram (not a script!), which will contain a combination of years and months:
if the data in the diagram, taking into account user filters, contains information for 12 months of the year in TOTAL, then the corresponding year is displayed, and if less than 12 in TOTAL - months are displayed. Aim: incomplete years should be ungrouped.

I've got this:
 Month|Year|#TestSum
 jan.23|2023|1
 feb.23|2023|1
 mar.23|2023|1
 apr.23|2023|1
 may.23|2023|1
 jun.23|2023|1
 jul.23|2023|1
 aug.23|2023|1
 sep.23|2023|1
 oct.23|2023|1
 nov.23|2023|1
 dec.23|2023|1
 jan.24|2024|1
 feb.24|2024|1


I need this:
 MyDimension|#TestSum
 2023|12
 jan.24|1
 feb.24|1


I have tried the following:
if(
Aggr(Count({$} Distinct [Month]),[Year])=12, 
Aggr(Max([Year]),[Year]),
Aggr(Max([Month]), [Year], [Month])
)

It doesn't work: I got almost all months of 2023.

Also I tried the following:
 if(
Aggr(Count({$} Distinct [Month]),[Year])=12, 
[Year],
[Month]
)

It doesn't work: almost same bad result.



Did you try this:
If(Aggr(Count(Distinct [Month]), [Year]) = 12,
    [Year], 
    [Month]
)

